# Is there a private version of readthedocs?

Tags: read-the-docs

I am developing an in house application which is proprietary, and I want to build and host the documentation somewhere. Due to the nature of it being proprietary, I cannot use the public version of readthedocs. Is there a paid or private version of http://readthedocs.org ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is https://readthedocs.com/ which appears to be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Another similar alternative is to use [Gitbook](http://www.gitbook.com), you can sync your docs from Github or Bitbucket repos.